# How to delete all rows under the quick filter column, filtered and unfiltered ones?

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I have a table with multiple columns and I do some filtering in those columns. The data I use in the table comes from external sources that I copy paste manually each time I need to analyze it - for the time being, there is no better way.

The issue I have is that I can't seem to be able to clear all the data from the table without clearing the filters. Even if I manually select a table range such as "2:500" and delete it, the filtered rows within this range are ignored and remain in the table.

How can I delete *all* data from the table without deleting the quick filter column including the filters in order to reuse it on new data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is formatted as an Excel Table (select any cell within the range, then choose Insert -> Tables -> Table), hover your mouse to the top of a cell in the header row. The pointer will change to a down-pointing arrow. Click and you will select the entire column. Then, right click and choose Delete -> Table Rows.

That way, you delete all contents of your table, but do not lose any formatting of the table, including the filters.

Comment: I just came around trying your solution. That's really helpful advice, thanks. I just noticed one thing: The visible rows are deleted in their entirety while with the filtered rows, only the content is cleared - the number of filtered rows is thus not changing. Is there any possibility to completely delete those rows, too?

Comment: After deleting the visible rows, select again the entire column (your table should be empty, but it will select the non-visible rows nevertheless) and go to Home -> Cells -> Delete -> Delete Table Rows. Now it will delete the non-visible rows.

Comment: You can also click on any cell on the table and go to Data -> Sort & Filter -> Clear. It will clear all your filters. Then you can delete all rows and there will be no non-visible rows, so you end up clearing your entire table.